# Qt how to open SQL Compact Server file .sdf

Tags: c++, sql-server, database, qt, sdf

I am trying to open a SQL Compact Server file .sdf with Qt.
I have the following code:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
db.setDatabaseName("C:\\testresults.sdf");
bool Success = db.open();

sprintf(writeToMonitorBuffer, "dblastError = %s", (const char *)db.lastError().text().toLatin1());
writeToMonitor(writeToMonitorBuffer);

sprintf(writeToMonitorBuffer, "db.open(): Success/Fail = %s", Success ? "Pass" : "Fail");
writeToMonitor(writeToMonitorBuffer);
```

I am getting the error message:

```
dblastError = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified QODBC3: Unable to connect
```

And I get:

```
db.open(): Success/Fail = Fail
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: you should rework the post to have proper formating of the code, is almost unreadable like this ...

Comment: In the past I have used<br>
db.setDatabaseName("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DSN='';DBQ=C:\\temp\\TestEng_TestDatabase.accdb");
for connection to an access database.

Seems like I should be doing something like,
db.setDatabaseName("Driver={SQL Server (*.sdf)};DSN='';DBQ=C:\\testresults.sdf");

But I am not sure what Driver={???} for sdf file.

Answer (score 1):

`\` is used for [escape sequences](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) in C++, so you need to do it like this instead:

`db.setDatabaseName("C:\\testresults.sdf");`